# mat-calendar returns undefined on first click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

mat-calendar returns undefined on the first click by date. second and other - works fine. First console.log will return undefined. And if there any way to close the mat-calendar after clicking on the date?
Here's the code

file.html

```
<mat-calendar (click)="onSelectDate($event)" #picker></mat-calendar>
```

file.ts

```
public onSelectDate(event): void {
    this.datePicker.selectedChange.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried (selectedChange) instead of (click)?

Comment: this might help https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: @Pilpo if there any method to close the calendar after selecting the date? Maybe with viewChild?

Comment: You might either use mat-datepicker as described on @PoulKruijt link or trick the matcalendar to close itself because its documentation shows there is no "close()" method you might call with your ViewChild('mat-calendar') https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts

Answer (score 0):

Bay be you don't bind ng module.
Consider another option for interacting with mat-calendar.
You can't use ViewChild